# How to solve an error regarding failed to initialise plugins in XAMPP?

Tags: mariadb, xampp

I have the following message when I try to start my database in XAMP:

> Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked port,
> missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by
> another method. Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the
> Windows Event Viewer for more clues. If you need more help, copy and
> post this entire log window on the forums.

Here are my logs errors:

> Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x5946)
>
> 2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please
> run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.########
> files
>
> **2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.**
>
> **2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.**
>
> 2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows
> interlocked functions
>
> 2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
>
> 2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
>
> 2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
>
> 2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
>
> 2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total
> size = 16M, instances =  1, chunk size = 16M
>
> 2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of
> buffer pool
>
> 2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments
> are active.
>
> 2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for
> temporary tables
>
> 2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file
> 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12  MB. Physically writing the
> file full; Please wait ...
>
> 2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1'
> size is now 12 MB.
>
> 2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>
> 2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence
> number 274011788; transaction id 115120
>
> 2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from
> C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
>
> 2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>
> 2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at
> 220831 17:08:07
>
> **2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded**
>
> **2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.**
>
> **2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [ERROR] Aborting**

How could I fix this? Thank you in advance for any attempt to clarify this!

Comment: Did you look at this line `2022-08-31 17:08:07 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files` and did you do as it suggested??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 12):

Stop the service. Delete from c:\xampp\mysql\data the files: "aria_log.00000001" and "aria_log_control" and start the service again. The files will be created again automatically and it will work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

To fix the error you just have to enter the mysql folder in xampp (in case of using xampp) then go to the data folder and delete aria_log.x files

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).